# python setup.py build with a given python version

Tags: python, cmd, installation, cython, setup.py

All,

I have several versions of Python installed. In the environment variables, i have two paths to site-packages folders.

In the cmd, I would like to do

```
python setup.py build
```

with one given version of Python, say the version at `D:\Python333\lib\site-packages`. But it keeps calling the wrong Python version, at, say, `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages`.

How can i have setup launched by the version of Python i wish ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `setup.py` with the Python version you want to install, e.g.

```
sudo python2.5 setup.py install
sudo python2.7 setup.py install
sudo python3.3 setup.py install
```

If your Python installation is somewhere else (e.g. because of [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)) make sure to activate the virtualenv first.

Comment: thanks. in fact, the setup.py is to use cython to compile .pyx files. i have to compile with a very precise version of cython in some folder. i would like to indicate which folder it is

Comment: Can you create a virtualenv for your cython installation?

Comment: i am compiling a library inside a huge collaborative project. i have to use one given python version, which is linked in the solution of this project. when i call in cmd, by default this is another version of python that is called, in another file location, and with no cython inside. what can i do ?

Comment: You need to at least set up the environment before running `setup.py`, at the very least making sure cython is in your `PATH`.